# 'Invalid Query' in FireStore on android project

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This the function function call when my activity is open.

```
public void startListening() {
    final Query query = collectionReference;
    listenerRegistration = query.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(1).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null)
                return;
            List<DocumentChange> documentChanges = documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges();
            if (documentSnapshots.getMetadata().isFromCache())
                return;
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : documentChanges) {
                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    start(documentChange.getDocument().getDate("timestamp"), query);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In here I'm fetching the maximum timestamp document and after that I'm calling again my new function "start" with sending parameter document date and query.

```
  private void start(Date date, Query query) {
    query.whereGreaterThan("timestamp", date).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null)
                return;
            List<DocumentChange> documentChanges = documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges();
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : documentChanges) {
                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)
                    fireStoreDocumentListener.onDocumentAdded(documentChange);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

At first line of this function my app crashes.

Log cat error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. 
>   You can only perform equality comparisons on null (via whereEqualTo()).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're calling `start` with a `date` that is equal to `null`, which is an illegal value for `whereGreaterThan`.

The best solution is to figure out where the `null` comes from and prevent it there. But a simpler alternative would be to not set the query when you get `null`:

```
private void start(Date date, Query query) {
  if (date != null) {
    query.whereGreaterThan("timestamp", date).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null)
                return;
            List<DocumentChange> documentChanges = documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges();
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : documentChanges) {
                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)
                    fireStoreDocumentListener.onDocumentAdded(documentChange);
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I see the date object is null.But I do not know why the date is null.Only the date object is missing @frank

Comment: Ahsan, maybe you are using firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp and the update has not arrived yet from the server, so "timestamp" does not contains a valid Date.